Correctly scaling eye texture onto sphere
I have applied an eye ball texture from turbosquid to a sphere but I cannot figure out how to scale it correctly. I have attached an image of my node set up and an image of how it is supposed to look. I have tried scaling in the mapping node but this does not work.Any Advice would be much appreciated.

The problem is not the scaling I guess, but you are using UV coordinates (which is most likely how the textures are supposed to work), and the question is has your eye a correct or in any way usable UV map?

Can you add just the texture to this post? I want to see how it’s shaped.

Hello hard to tell without the file
